# How to clone or make a copy of non-Object type (not an instanceof Object) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, clone

I have a third party plugin object which gets refreshed and in turn loses the context while refreshing. It is of type IXMLData1 (which is not instanceof Object). 
This non-Object consists of a few members/methods and a parent of same type.

Is there any way to clone such type of non-Object in JavaScript?

Comment: Look at the prototype chain, it is an object.

Comment: If not object then is it string?

Comment: A string is an object too....  Type this in your console:  `"123".__proto__.__proto__`

Comment: @Superdrac A `string` (literal) is not an object in Javascript, but when you try to access a property of it, it is automatically converted to a `String` (captial S) which is an object. [Distinction between string primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is an object...

Comment: Maybe you should try with lodash [`_.clone()`](https://lodash.com/docs#clone)

Comment: @idmean Primitive values are not objects.

Comment: @Oriol Of course, yes, though they are easily promoted to objects.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to clone an object which is not an instance of the Object constructor. But that shouldn't mater much, you can still copy the properties as usual.

Comment: @Oriol: True that. The object is not an instance of Object. I tried using dojo's `_clone()` and jQuery's `extend()` way too. But that did not help as these 2 deals with the objects which are instance of Object.

Comment: @SatishMadiwal Please include an example of that object. What is `IXMLData1`?